# Can you compare a parameter to another parameter using ChoiceFormat?

Tags: java, libgdx

I'm currently using the `I18NBundle` ([wiki](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Internationalization-and-Localization)  | [docs](https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/utils/I18NBundle.html)) package from LibGDX to do some internationalization for my game. the `I18NBundle` internally uses the java `MessageFormat` ([docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/MessageFormat.html)) to format strings such as this:

```
// The string to format.
shields = Shields: {0, number, integer}

// Do the formatting
bundle.format("shields", 5);
>> Shields: 5
```

It can also do conditionals like so:

```
// # = if exact
// < = if greater than
shields = Shields: {0, choice, 0# No Shields! | 1# One Shield! | 1< {0, number, integer} Shields!}

bundle.format("shields", 0);
>> Shields: No Shield!

bundle.format("shields", 1);
>> Shields: One Shield!

bundle.format("shields", 5);
>> Shields: 5 Shields!
```

Now I'm trying to compare two input parameters to each other. I tried this:

```
// If parameter 1 is greater than parameter 0...
score = Score: {0, choice, {1}< {0} New high score! | {0}}

bundle.format("score", newScore, highScore);

// Expected Output if new score is lesser than high score
bundle.format("score", 1, 5);
>> Score: 1

// Expected output if new score is greater than high score
bundle.format("score", 7, 5);
>> Score: 7 New high score!
```

But this throws an exception since it is invalid formatting. So my question is: **Is it possible to compare two input parameters to each other when using `ChoiceFormat`?**

Comment: Can you pass a boolean? You could try a workaround by passing a boolean parameter of value param1 < param2

Comment: @CedricMartens Technically yes but it gets coerced to a String sadly. It actually seems like all inputs gets coerced to Strings since if you pass an (say `new Object()`) it appears in the same way as if you would do `System.out.println(new Object())`.

Comment: and if from there you try doing {0} == "true"? Since if it coerces it to a String it should be "true"

Comment: @CedricMartens Unfortunately that's invalid syntax. From [this link](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/MessageFormat.html) it also seems like the only valid inputs are `number, date, time, choice` (and `String` if you don't supply a type), no boolean or other types allowed!

Answer (score 1):

You can use this workaround of using a `number` (0 for false and 1 for true) instead of a `boolean`, since a `boolean` is not permitted.

```
condition=Score: {0,choice,0#Cool Score, but {1, number} is less than {2, number}!|1#New Highscore of {1, number}!}
```

This code :

```
int highScore = 15;
int newScore = 20;

boolean isHighScore = newScore > highScore;

//I use a ternary if in order to translate the boolean into a number since booleans
//are not accepted by ChoiceFormat
String res = i18NBundle.format("condition", isHighScore ? 1 : 0, newScore, highScore);
System.out.println(res);

//I test again with a new score that is not the highscore
if(isHighScore)
    highScore = newScore;

newScore = 13;
isHighScore = newScore > highScore;
String res2 =i18NBundle.format("condition", isHighScore ? 1 : 0, newScore, highScore);
System.out.println(res2);
```

Outputs :

```
Score: New Highscore of 20!
Score: Cool Score, but 13 is less than 20!
```

Comment: I'm perfectly aware of this workaround (it's how I do it atm) I just wanted to know if there's a way to do it just using the format itself. +1 anyways though.